# generate migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I try to create a standalone migration file by executing the following command:

```
rails generate migration LoadData
```

But I got the following error:

```
 PATH-TO/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)

 PATH-TO/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
 ...
```

I am using **Rails v2.3** and **ruby Enterprise edition**. Why I got this error, how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an incompatibility between some version of Rails 2.3.xx and recent versions of RubyGems. I got this error with Rails 2.3.4 and then used a more recent version of Rails 2.3.11 as of now to get rid of this error.

In case it is not possible to update the Rails version, then in your RakeFile add in the beginning.

```
require "thread"
```

Downgrading the RubyGems version will also help. Afaik Rubygems version 1.3.5 is compatible  with Rails 2.3.4 and 2.3.5.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is it possible to try the more recent versions of Rails 2.3 ? or downgrade rubygems ? The former sounds safer.

Comment: Ok, I see, though I can not change the Rails version, but I see your point, I am using Rails v2.3.2 which is old. Anyhow I will accept your answer and try to find out an workaround for the migrations. Thank you.

Comment: thanks. I am trying to reproduce the error again. If i find any solution I will let you know. Could you tell me your rubygems version ?

Comment: my 'gem -v' gives the version 1.8.10 . Thank you.